# Why is SOQL query is returning deleted Opportunity split record

Tags: soql, query, opportunity, delete, opportunity-split

I have an Opportunity, under which I had initially added two Opportunity split records. But later I deleted one of the Split records among them using the delete button in the UI, as I didn't need it anymore.

But after that when I query for the Opportunity split records for this particular Opportunity using the following query,

```
SELECT Id, SplitOwnerId, OpportunityId, SplitPercentage, SplitOwner.Id, SplitOwner.FirstName, SplitOwner.LastName, SplitOwner.Email, isDeleted FROM OpportunitySplit WHERE Opportunity.Id = '0062h00000RHMH9AAP'
```

I am still receiving the deleted record too. And the 'isDeleted' value is false too. I am attaching the screenshot of the same below.

can someone please let me know why is the query returning the deleted record too with the existing record? Thanks in advance.

[image: Existing split in the UI after deleting another split]

The above image is of the existing single split in the UI after deleting another split.

[image]

The above image shows another split returning through query even after deletion.

Comment: Seems strange as I can't reproduce this behaviour in my org. Can you check if this happens in your other orgs(Like sandbox) too?Also when using third-party tool like workbench, does it give same result?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a resolution?
While I can't reproduce your exact issue above, I am noticing that deleting an opportunity split through the related list UI is causing behavior as if the record was never deleted.
(A flow's criteria is being triggered by the supposedly deleted record)

Comment: Changing the Opportunity Owner after the Opportunity is closed won will create a new Owner as split record with 100% split along with the old owner too. This will result in two split records with a 100% split. In this case, the old split record has to be manually deleted through workbench or any other ETL tool, as the old split won't be visible in UI, and deleting it in the UI won't make any difference either as it stays in the Database. Deleting the old record through the workbench solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind this is when the Opportunity Owner is changed and the split associated with that owner is removed manually from UI after the Opportunity is Closed-Won, the Split of the previous Owner will still continue to exist with the split percentage of 100 even though it's not visible in the UI.

And with that, the new split record for the new Split Owner will also be added. Which makes the Opportunity to have two Split records with split percentages of 100. This scenario occurs only when the Opportunity Owner is changed after the Opportunity is Closed-Won. If the Owner is changed before the Opportunity is closed won, then this can be avoided.

In this above scenario as deleting from the UI will not make any difference, the record has to be deleted through workbench or any other tools where you can see the database data.